# Copying links on mobile phones

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I am trying to create a button on a mobile website that when the button is clicked, a link (e.g. example.com) is copied to the user's clipboard.

The user can then paste this link in an email or a text message or into his browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Direct copying to the clipboard is not permitted by modern browsers for security reasons. What you can do is to let the browser select a piece of text for the user to select and copy.

An example that uses this method is [Google's URL shortener](https://goo.gl/)